# Cannot integrate Twitter in Node Red

Tags: twitter, node-red

I try to use 'Twitter in' node in Node Red to receive info, but it always displays an error message:

[image]

I've also config for an API key, API secret key, Access Token and Access Token secret.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using essential access, or elevated? Essential access only has access to the Twitter API v2, and the Node-RED nodes do not currently use that version of the API.

Comment: Hi Andy, I am using essential access, how can I avoid using it? I see that do not have another option for me to choose when creating app. Thanks!

Comment: You will either need to apply for Elevated access in the Twitter Developer portal, or find a Node-RED plugin node that supports Twitter API v2

Comment: Thanks Any, I have just changed to Elevated access and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

The main reason for this problem is twitter API upgrade to V2.0. I have developed a Node-red twitter node that searches public tweets using twitter API V2.0. You can download the code from my github: https://github.com/shahramdj/nodered_twitter_api

I also created a youtube video that explains how you can update the twitter node in node-red to search public tweets: The main reason for this problem is twitter API upgrade to V2.0. I have developed a Node-red twitter node that searches public tweets using twitter API V2.0. You can download the code from my github: https://github.com/shahramdj/nodered_twitter_api

I also created a youtube video that explains how you can update the twitter node in node-red to search public tweets: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HYn3sIDcIv4&t=78s